# Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent when using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

I'm trying to use dompdf on my plugin to create a save as pdf functionality,but I'm still getting 
`Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent`.

I've done some research and the solutions won't work. I've also use `exit()` as one of the answers suggest but it doesn't work.

Here is my current code

```
include(WPtest_PLUGIN_PATH.'/admin/includes/dompdf/lib/html5lib/Parser.php');
include(WPtest_PLUGIN_PATH.'/admin/includes/dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/Autoloader.php');
include(WPtest_PLUGIN_PATH.'/admin/includes/dompdf/lib/php-svg-lib/src/autoload.php');
include(WPtest_PLUGIN_PATH.'/admin/includes/dompdf/src/Autoloader.php');
Dompdf\Autoloader::register();

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class WPtest_Save_PDF{

    //use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    function __construct(){
        add_shortcode( 'save_me',array($this,'print_callback'));
    }       


    function print_callback(){

        if(isset($_GET['print']))
        {


            $dompdf = new Dompdf();

            $dompdf->loadHtml("test");

            // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
            $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

            // Render the HTML as PDF
            $dompdf->render();

            // Output the generated PDF to Browser
            $dompdf->stream();

            exit();
        }

    }
}

new WPtest_Save_PDF;
```

Comment: Can you try with hooking the pdf generation code to admin_init ?

Comment: I'm going to replace the add_shorcode right?with add action?

Comment: yeah. please have a try

Comment: @JomolMJ something like this? https://www.screencast.com/t/9WkA3KWuY it is still not working.

Comment: yeah. Anything worked?

Comment: None atm, It was very easy when I've use it on a single php file,but after I integrated it on wordpress it's taking me so much time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162013/discussion-between-jomol-mj-and-rai-nalasa).

Comment: There is a site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your wordpress already sent some data to the browser, and when any data is sent, the headers are sent as well.

I would suggest you to use buffers (ob_start, ob_end_flush, ...) but it's on a general purpose, I do not know if it is appliable in your case, i'm not really working with wordpress structure.

Comment: I've tried that as well using `ob_start` ,`ob_get_content`, `ob_end_clean`.